# How to mock out a function that is not exposed from within __init__ file?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-module

The code structure is as follows.

service_a/__init__.py:

```
from .func_a import func_a
```

service_a/func_a.py

```
def func_a():
     ...
```

service_b/__init__.py:

```
from .func_b import func_b
```

service_b/func_b.py:

```
from service_a import func_a
def func_b():
     func_a()
     ...
```

Now when I unit test `func_b`, I'm not sure about how to mock out `func_a`. My test code is like:

```
from unittest import mock
from service_b import func_b

# within test method:
with mock.patch('[patch_path_for_func_a]') as mock_func:
    func_b()
    ...
```

I don't know what to put in `[patch_path_for_func_a]` because `func_a` isn't exposed from `service_b` at runtime.

Comment: I can improve my question if you feel it's unclear or invalid. Please leave a comment before you downvote silently.

Comment: Did you read the relevant documentation? Is there something you don't understand? If you read and understood the documentation you should have an idea of what to do. What did you try? Why did you think it would work? What happened instead?

Comment: @Goyo Thanks for your comment. May I ask which part of my question is unclear to you?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you really want to do this there are ways but probably not a nice one. For example, you might add `service_b` to `sys.path` so that module `func_b` can be imported:

```
import sys
from unittest import mock

import service_b
sys.path.extend(service_b.__path__)
import func_b

with mock.patch('func_b.func_a') as mock_func: 
    func_b.func_b()
    mock_func.assert_called_once_with()
```

Now if you think that trying to write this test has been painful I suggest you take a step back to identify the source of the pain and get rid of it. You are actively hiding the module `service_b.func_b` so that it can't be easily imported, then your test wants to do exactly that. Different parts of the code have opposite goals and that is what is causing the pain.

These are several ways in which you can avoid this, they might or might not work well for your specific case (it is hard to give concrete advice about foobar examples):

### Do not hide the module

If you do not give the same name to module and the function or somehow you reorganize your code so that the module where `func_a()` is being looked up can be easily imported the problem vanishes.

### Do not mock func_a()

`func_b()` calling `func_a()` looks like an implementation detail so it might make sense if the test does not care about it. Just call `func_b()` and assert that it returns the expected value.

### Make the dependency explicit

If you really feel that the test should call `func_b()` with an alternate implementation  (in this case a mock) of `func_a()` that is a hint that other code might want to do the same thing. Making the dependency explicit will make that way easier for any code, including the test, and will avoid the need of monkey-patching and the distraction of having to think where to patch.

```
def func_b(func_a):
    func_a()
    ...
```

And then the test is straightforward (no monkey-patching, no strained imports, no irrelevant and distracting details):

```
func_a = mock.Mock()  # arrange
func_b(func_a)  # act
func_a.assert_called_once_with()  # assert
```